# When building the library matio, the configure script throws the error "C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

For building the library [matio](https://github.com/tbeu/matio), I first need to execute a configure script and afterwards run make. The configure script however throws the following error:

```
    configure: error: in `/home/user/matio-master':                                    
    configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

More specifically, the error happens while executing core tests. Below you see a section of the config.log. What could be the reason for the fail and how can I fix it?

```
    ## ----------- ##
    ## Core tests. ##
    ## ----------- ##

    configure:2135: checking for a BSD-compatible install
    configure:2203: result: /usr/bin/install -c
    configure:2214: checking whether build environment is sane
    configure:2274: result: yes
    configure:2415: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
    configure:2454: result: /bin/mkdir -p
    configure:2467: checking for gawk
    configure:2483: found /bin/gawk
    configure:2494: result: gawk
    configure:2505: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
    configure:2527: result: yes
    configure:2622: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
    configure:2631: result: no
    configure:2651: checking build system type
    configure:2669: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    configure:2691: checking host system type
    configure:2706: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    configure:2819: checking for pgcc
    configure:2849: result: no
    configure:2819: checking for icc
    configure:2849: result: no
    configure:2819: checking for gcc
    configure:2835: found /home/user/gcc
    configure:2846: result: gcc
    configure:2880: checking for C compiler version
    configure:2888: gcc --version >&5
    gcc (GCC) 6.3.0
    Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    configure:2892: $? = 0
    configure:2899: gcc -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0/bin/gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/sysmnt/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
    Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
    Configured with: ../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0 --with-isl=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0 --with-gmp=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0 --with-mpfr=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0 --with-mpc=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/6.3.0 --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --disable-werror --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,java,go,objc,obj-c++ --enable-c99 --disable-libada --enable-plugin --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-long-long --disable-multilib
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC) 
    configure:2903: $? = 0
    configure:2910: gcc -V >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:2914: $? = 1
    configure:2937: checking for C compiler default output file name
    configure:2959: gcc -L/boost_filesystem -L/boost_system   conftest.c  >&5
    configure:2963: $? = 0
    configure:3001: result: 
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h.  */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "MATIO"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "matio"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.5.13"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "MATIO 1.5.13"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "t-beu@users.sourceforge.net"
    | #define PACKAGE "matio"
    | #define VERSION "1.5.13"
    | #define MATIO_PLATFORM "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
    | #define MATIO_MAJOR_VERSION 1
    | #define MATIO_MINOR_VERSION 5
    | #define MATIO_RELEASE_LEVEL 13
    | #define MATIO_VERSION 1513
    | #define MATIO_VERSION_STR "1.5.13"
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    | 
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    | 
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:3007: error: in `/home/user/matio-master':
    configure:3010: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: `/home/user/matio-master' is write-protected OR executables are running?

Comment: actually that was the issue, did not have the correct permissions on the folder .. thanks a lot